# How to build a low latency audio streaming android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, streaming

We are trying to stream live audio record from the phone's mic to a server but experiencing a 200ms delay, and would like to minimize it.

Is there a good API/an efficient way or protocol to do this?
we though about using SIP/RTP protocol somehow, would it be more efficient?

here's the code, what would you recommend changing?

```
package com.awesome.audiostream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button startButton,stopButton;

    public byte[] buffer;
    public static DatagramSocket socket;
    private int port=12345;

    AudioRecord recorder;

    private int sampleRate = 176400;
    private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

    private boolean status = true;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View mv = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        setContentView(mv);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start_button);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);

        startButton.setOnClickListener (startListener);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener (stopListener);

    }

    private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            status = false;
            recorder.release();
            Log.d("VS","Recorder released");
        }
    };

    private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            status = true;
            startStreaming();
        }
    };

    public void startStreaming() {
        Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                    Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                    DatagramPacket packet;

                    // The IP address of the server receiving the audio stream
                    final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.204");
                    Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");

                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*10);
                    Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");
                    recorder.startRecording();

                    while(status) {
                        //reading data from MIC into buffer
                        minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        //putting buffer in the packet
                        packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);

                        socket.send(packet);
                        System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " +minBufSize);
                    }

                } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                    Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                }
            }

        });
        streamThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but, for what it may be worth, the main bottleneck on Android is usually the audio capture minimum buffer size, not many devices are able to provide small buffers. What values are you getting?

Regarding APIs, you may want to check out this documentation, if you haven't yet:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/audio-latency

Then you have the buffering on the receiver side, to compensate for momentary high network loads where the desired audio bitrate cannot be met: it's a trade-off between latency and stability of the stream, a buffer underrun will translate in audible artifacts. You need to select a transmission protocol, a codec and a media player that allows you to minimize that buffering.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new checklist for enabling low latency on Android at:
https://developer.android.com/games/sdk/oboe/low-latency-audio#oboe

It was focussed on games but most of applies to any app.

1. Use Oboe
2. Request performance mode "low latency"
3. Request sharing mode "exclusive"
4. Use 48000 Hz or the Oboe sample rate converter
5. Set usage to AAUDIO_USAGE_GAME
6. Use data callbacks
7. Avoid blocking operations in the callback
8. Tune buffer size to "double buffer"